# rendering asp.net controls on IIS

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, iis

I am using IIS 5.1 on server 2000. I have set the asp.net page for custom error in IIS which is directing to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Custom_Error\IIS_Error.aspx.

Custom error page appears when user keyin wrong password for 3 times.

When i access the error page directly (for testing) from my laptop using following URL then i can see the page text and the text box.

//192.168.0.10/Custom_Error/IIS_Error.aspx

But when user keyin wrong password for 3 times, system shows the custom error page with text only and doesn't show the asp.net controls.

Also, is there any way to show the local path from where the user has been redirected to the custom error page? For an example; we have got 10 folders under website called TestWeb, so when the user is accessing folder number (3) called webtest3 and custom error page should show webtest3 on the page.

Can i do it either on asp.net or on asp classic page?

Comment: Based on the IP address, the link that you've shared is local to your machine, if you're adding it to demonstrate what you're seeing, you should attach a picture/post to a screen shot.

Comment: ip address is to show where the file sits not for demo.

Comment: You've asked two questions. In the future, please consider asking separately.  Also, it may help if you post some code samples here. I've answered your second question below, but your first question about asp.net controls is difficult to answer without seeing what the code looks like

Comment: I have fixed this issue by creating a simple html page for custom errors and redirecting it to asp.net page. Asp.net Custom error page doesn't work for IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked two questions.  I will answer your second question, "how to get the local path the user has been redirected from to the custom error page?"

It depends on how you are directing the user to the error page.  If you direct the user to the custom error page by handling uncaught exceptions in global.asax, you can write something like this:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
    Exception ex = Context.Server.GetLastError();
    // do something with url and exception data
}
```

If you are manually redirecting the user to the error page, say with `Response.Redirect`, there are several ways you may accomplish this.

Normally, web browsers will send to the web server the address of the page they just came from, but some users (and some firewalls) will disable this functionality.  When the data is available, you can normally get it by calling `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];`.

However, if you want to be sure you get the data, consider saving the URL of the page where the error occurs just before redirecting the user to the error page like this:

```
if (error_condition) 
{
    Session["error_url"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
    Response.Redirect(error_page);
}
```

Comment: Hi, i am trying to do in asp classic as asp.net page is not showing server controls. I am have tried this command <%response.write(Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO"))%> but it doesn't do anything. even simple response.write command does't write anything.

Comment: you did specify asp.net as a question tag.  In any event, we may be better able to provide help if you provide some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by creating a simple html page for custom errors and redirecting it to asp.net page.

Asp.net Custom error page doesn't work properly for IIS. It is better to have a html page instead.